# Trouble with LOD calc for total sum of dimension

Tags: math, tableau-api

Can someone help me with a tableau LOD calc? I think thats what I need here in order to sum found and not found - I'd like to have another calculated field that will add found+not =337

[image]

Here's a mocked up example with two more calculated fields the one labeled 'math' is easy but I cant get the total sum calc right :(

[image]

Comment: I got your point. But in order to help you with exact calculations I'll need a snapshot of your data along with field names and it's aggregation/disaggregation level.

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works, else give me some data to show you.

```
{sum{[Native C3])}
```